# windows 'switch to' implementation

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

Hi how can i  implement "switch to" functional in my app like in windows task explorer, can any one give me useful link or response how to do it?
Tnaks a lot for all

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking about, could you edit your question and provide some more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the normal way to change "current task", for "task switcher" apps, [SwitchToThisWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a better solution since it does not require your app to be "foreground" (But please, don't abuse SwitchToThisWindow just to bring your own apps to the foreground)

If this is a alt-tab like application, you can use [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register for a special key press, and [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate top-level windows...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SwitchToThisWindow()` Windows API function in User32.dll. Get a handle to the window using `EnumWindows()` or `FindWindow()`, then pass it to `SwitchToThisWindow()` to switch to the app.